# How can I get the density of many points?

Tags: plotting

I have many points as follows:

```
{{-0.0471439, 0.299463, -0.0779012}, {0.262537, 
  0.289975, -0.116354}, {-0.0282801, 
  0.273016, -0.102687}, {0.00323841, 0.159102, -0.0909938}, {0.06169, 
  0.100688, -0.441619}, {0.200391, -0.0162189, -0.225342}, {0.241363, 
  0.266076, 0.209348}, {0.328219, 0.235984, -0.127262}, {-0.312765, 
  0.232097, 0.1977}, {0.282049, 0.275197, -0.0516513}, {-0.238874, 
  0.218365, -0.352748}, {0.100943, 0.0731695, -0.212621}, {-0.313744, 
  0.00425549, -0.17235}, {0.280713, 0.226624, 0.239457}, {-0.0338427, 
  0.218521, -0.405946}, {0.252438, -0.245801, 0.161007}, {-0.112881, 
  0.298048, -0.0174432}, {-0.153356, -0.260483, 
  0.0739117}, {0.324989, -0.0748251, 0.0462554}, {-0.00912448, 
  0.434139, 0.0820614}, {-0.235592, 0.219753, 0.0188258}, {0.340868, 
  0.34294, 0.00859157}, {-0.401194, 
  0.180649, -0.0854585}, {-0.00343112, -0.231167, 
  0.188466}, {0.188431, 0.00729554, 
  0.328137}, {0.422104, -0.0358791, -0.17056}, {-0.310438, -0.244086, \
-0.00878584}, {-0.0146218, -0.298476, -0.0446437}, {-0.110352, 
  0.0409301, 0.123383}, {0.175694, 0.0359125, 0.382318}, {0.446906, 
  0.028996, 0.127431}, {0.275572, 
  0.255005, -0.143965}, {-0.0116579, -0.00365271, 
  0.405179}, {-0.162797, 0.314859, -0.0822421}, {0.121122, -0.146943, 
  0.425243}, {0.0645271, -0.464867, -0.0659728}, {-0.116964, 
  0.414343, -0.0548751}, {-0.0815424, -0.345495, -0.0291975}, \
{-0.190979, -0.0655358, -0.324155}, {-0.281223, 0.00971276, 
  0.0761003}, {0.250182, -0.38709, 0.0376813}, {0.0814187, 
  0.119792, -0.204879}, {0.467335, 
  0.0928268, -0.0527096}, {-0.0385966, -0.213283, -0.214491}, \
{0.100831, 
  0.343383, -0.0798391}, {-0.354847, -0.194766, -0.238211}, \
{0.238362, -0.0677096, -0.126659}, {-0.0137679, 0.0802426, 
  0.457345}, {-0.179647, 0.0735849, -0.446563}, {-0.29321, 
  0.0881871, -0.25162}, {-0.211352, -0.248084, 
  0.106522}, {-0.317301, -0.0135673, -0.0691255}, {-0.264986, \
-0.2419, -0.24643}, {-0.208139, -0.235632, 
  0.380122}, {-0.372791, -0.100073, 0.181628}, {-0.268618, 
  0.334647, -0.106111}, {-0.247005, 
  0.423785, -0.0654836}, {0.251981, -0.0441717, 0.152466}, {-0.270417,
   0.00297152, -0.29173}, {0.249685, -0.0369006, -0.132995}, \
{0.0561088, 0.181036, 
  0.0612114}, {0.0747368, -0.0625052, -0.167164}, {0.0703647, \
-0.0339969, 0.414565}, {0.195487, 0.0546623, 0.132556}, {0.0938212, 
  0.369074, 0.175771}, {0.131477, 0.46966, -0.0935598}, {0.0786577, 
  0.218496, 0.0168249}, {-0.0934283, -0.0213665, 
  0.285788}, {-0.364959, -0.216234, 0.247283}, {0.336975, 
  0.141949, -0.268787}, {-0.209329, 0.397111, 
  0.120625}, {0.212091, -0.181346, -0.169864}, {-0.221016, \
-0.00802944, 0.19701}, {-0.247103, 0.0224859, 0.113576}, {-0.094958, 
  0.14063, 0.211299}, {-0.291031, -0.338033, -0.0430127}, {0.102312, 
  0.28245, 0.248906}, {0.317189, 0.0428664, 
  0.227461}, {0.294883, -0.327932, 
  0.168985}, {0.144419, -0.294379, -0.240564}, {-0.0774357, \
-0.0835766, 0.39815}, {-0.397364, 0.0470646, 
  0.0891191}, {0.100986, -0.157648, 0.0420302}, {-0.309599, 0.176025, 
  0.286379}, {0.108131, 0.411362, 0.0432084}, {0.157548, 
  0.249592, -0.223264}, {-0.0783986, 0.176774, 
  0.0378477}, {-0.376231, -0.194093, 
  0.0797716}, {0.0679584, -0.224474, 0.152114}, {-0.250028, 
  0.216657, -0.0491747}, {-0.139852, 
  0.32562, -0.0564879}, {-0.0498864, -0.124771, 0.364305}, {0.290468, 
  0.132962, 0.0326033}, {0.152325, -0.348887, -0.320713}, {-0.416669, 
  0.162283, -0.113481}, {0.0796525, -0.296461, -0.369576}, \
{-0.314039, -0.272856, 0.265865}, {0.198625, 
  0.360252, -0.00716511}, {0.305047, -0.0552484, -0.0984265}, \
{-0.0309463, -0.308138, 
  0.247146}, {-0.370698, -0.235762, -0.0401299}, {-0.416587, \
-0.0499201, -0.251557}, {-0.161223, -0.239434, -0.16376}, \
{-0.0192629, -0.414832, 
  0.252057}, {0.23315, -0.345409, -0.0721316}, {-0.199307, 
  0.362686, -0.194802}, {-0.113597, -0.297228, 0.178044}, {-0.228243, 
  0.175067, 0.388622}, {0.115252, 0.17066, 0.271099}, {0.379686, 
  0.230199, -0.132672}, {-0.255116, 
  0.117844, -0.307696}, {-0.21992, -0.06873, 
  0.395153}, {0.346574, -0.129263, -0.0801969}, {-0.0267095, \
-0.06381, -0.139009}, {-0.220005, 
  0.00212017, -0.0362607}, {0.174836, -0.0385845, 
  0.0661383}, {0.180999, -0.107712, -0.287318}, {-0.295086, 0.254319, 
  0.312808}, {-0.349595, 0.0201149, -0.29825}, {0.121684, -0.0256645, 
  0.0967809}, {-0.380725, -0.108729, -0.213378}, {-0.0764691, 
  0.290011, -0.18577}, {0.141098, 0.164843, 0.102128}, {-0.0655837, 
  0.240624, -0.415331}, {-0.0893252, -0.349134, -0.127519}, {0.318319,
   0.0539604, -0.221385}, {0.00862651, 
  0.235737, -0.406074}, {0.0471132, -0.271716, -0.0651186}, {0.313138,
   0.022518, 0.0167834}, {-0.143565, -0.28692, 0.267113}, {-0.441944, 
  0.132342, -0.00106901}, {0.153035, 0.00273222, 
  0.312221}, {-0.451798, -0.0458552, 
  0.161668}, {0.213927, -0.104646, -0.137742}, {0.104697, -0.131159, \
-0.385713}, {-0.0750184, 0.414073, -0.0467773}, {0.0175101, -0.031242,
   0.0839546}, {-0.0436725, -0.0481112, -0.236639}, {-0.189732, \
-0.17777, 0.0756617}, {0.0604398, 0.419866, 
  0.0541879}, {-0.128312, -0.418878, -0.177505}, {0.143495, 
  0.164876, -0.123344}, {0.169005, -0.258909, 0.293159}, {-0.222421, 
  0.356322, 0.123194}, {-0.17816, 0.249486, -0.146048}, {0.352419, 
  0.171446, 0.203226}, {0.00525244, -0.352239, 
  0.0212118}, {0.266389, -0.0814174, 
  0.0496242}, {0.00165655, -0.10701, 
  0.152365}, {-0.326238, -0.0793211, 0.167243}, {-0.0398336, 
  0.197756, -0.283359}, {-0.140386, -0.346196, 
  0.195933}, {-0.208087, -0.334471, 0.079663}, {-0.21444, -0.180893, 
  0.267172}, {0.169783, 0.399046, -0.24745}, {-0.106167, 
  0.169717, -0.337122}, {-0.0441954, -0.315688, 
  0.303719}, {0.138996, -0.0646095, 
  0.374281}, {-0.273786, -0.290388, -0.0739981}, {-0.431634, \
-0.125057, 0.027352}, {0.153883, 
  0.337588, -0.329101}, {0.132752, -0.47002, -0.00761463}, {0.241207, \
-0.136701, -0.362653}, {0.000201272, -0.144841, -0.165877}, {0.24848, \
-0.138821, -0.0181015}, {-0.193504, -0.0696694, -0.384456}, \
{0.279853, -0.011648, 0.373611}, {-0.406785, 0.0839666, 
  0.0268501}, {0.146882, 0.0168334, 
  0.297136}, {-0.166116, -0.112072, -0.061344}, {-0.0812807, \
-0.113327, 
  0.0957694}, {-0.1484, -0.436425, -0.134411}, {0.114231, -0.089962, \
-0.167537}, {0.00269207, -0.0246711, 
  0.00174364}, {0.079579, -0.302392, 
  0.154541}, {0.0156544, -0.0986176, -0.333578}, {-0.182716, \
-0.0266084, -0.189309}, {-0.200731, -0.0964, -0.413588}, {0.292491, \
-0.0751349, -0.188257}, {0.0154024, 0.0475554, 0.0730775}, {0.0800136,
   0.0451806, -0.252637}, {-0.206908, -0.0824018, 
  0.053479}, {-0.228407, -0.301778, -0.186451}, {-0.0143185, 
  0.251115, -0.307378}, {0.105792, 0.0922671, -0.281415}, {0.156038, 
  0.172443, -0.339487}, {-0.129627, 0.223106, 0.209583}, {-0.0649534, 
  0.0322796, -0.176213}, {-0.134145, -0.10276, 0.0364328}, {-0.171813,
   0.129584, -0.105468}, {-0.0506223, -0.170021, -0.0367011}, \
{-0.00835509, 
  0.356798, -0.163583}, {0.23635, -0.0300396, -0.329121}, {0.109177, 
  0.421806, 0.172296}, {0.228347, 0.244284, 0.236312}, {0.208056, 
  0.406541, -0.133694}, {-0.227908, -0.380321, -0.19953}, {-0.166075, 
  0.372934, -0.122634}, {0.162766, 0.0305652, -0.0504929}, {0.0646623,
   0.143905, -0.325067}, {0.354978, 
  0.239878, -0.193847}, {0.241568, -0.202832, -0.287255}, {-0.435229, \
-0.0591351, -0.143724}, {-0.430563, 
  0.139394, -0.00569495}, {-0.218621, -0.158002, 
  0.415087}, {-0.19592, -0.392325, -0.218021}, {0.305905, 
  0.0975416, -0.18711}, {-0.207089, -0.354042, -0.244566}, {0.18364, \
-0.134596, -0.119433}, {-0.129418, -0.239025, -0.414519}, \
{-0.0555786, -0.0415161, -0.358319}, {0.120298, 0.190541, 
  0.444099}, {0.00695635, 0.444591, -0.218955}, {-0.251121, 0.411539, 
  0.0551908}, {-0.157477, -0.00198992, -0.252328}, {-0.242449, 
  0.223308, 0.0163051}, {0.28081, 0.252071, 0.0240758}, {-0.0132641, 
  0.230131, -0.220803}, {-0.0569238, 0.109623, -0.36512}, {0.489674, 
  0.0130726, 0.0483428}, {-0.250558, 0.407403, 0.14063}, {0.203717, 
  0.242093, -0.365234}, {0.076652, -0.32327, -0.268491}, {-0.222007, 
  0.00178315, -0.0614686}, {-0.377412, 
  0.0683759, -0.0313587}, {-0.175519, -0.301138, -0.154297}, \
{-0.263793, 0.0374982, 
  0.330548}, {-0.256827, -0.104815, -0.132308}, {-0.0863108, \
-0.0296881, -0.273954}, {-0.171948, -0.210852, -0.315172}, \
{-0.0614181, 0.129389, -0.135757}, {0.161085, 
  0.273408, -0.277}, {0.159583, -0.293613, -0.315274}, {0.122818, \
-0.358244, 0.235489}, {-0.0276678, 
  0.47226, -0.0581904}, {-0.127271, -0.103187, 0.323628}, {-0.389268, 
  0.26163, 0.0586258}, {-0.33076, -0.00401511, -0.271056}, {-0.25092, 
  0.208422, -0.254305}, {0.217855, -0.0979218, 
  0.373871}, {0.204574, -0.4076, 0.180469}, {-0.110849, 0.185703, 
  0.411527}, {-0.0452311, 0.163945, -0.310455}, {-0.346834, -0.154335,
   0.0661192}, {-0.180303, -0.422936, -0.041271}, {-0.317588, \
-0.117914, 
  0.328641}, {-0.107218, -0.165349, -0.273707}, {0.159232, -0.28344, \
-0.0309057}, {-0.331021, 0.00304606, -0.291184}, {-0.144769, 0.427684,
   0.129703}, {-0.133151, -0.186211, -0.124577}, {0.42955, -0.0978176,
   0.194142}, {-0.382059, 0.19408, -0.192805}, {-0.36881, -0.012274, 
  0.216405}, {0.140528, 0.284212, 0.21902}, {0.154821, 0.158429, 
  0.0854519}, {0.487343, 
  0.0504136, -0.0331168}, {0.0615617, -0.00604159, 
  0.216147}, {-0.0426196, -0.236559, -0.341565}, {0.152254, -0.244392,
   0.232937}, {0.307941, -0.0498151, 0.2491}, {-0.0134551, -0.0905183,
   0.463679}, {0.116194, -0.0684238, 0.386138}, {-0.0500234, 
  0.0876851, 0.0740857}, {0.0714134, 
  0.0020847, -0.320488}, {-0.167051, -0.309789, 
  0.0676173}, {0.0213635, -0.183229, -0.0548717}, {-0.248731, 
  0.0791151, -0.0731907}, {-0.139068, 
  0.0751659, -0.322801}, {0.0616435, 0.0411149, 
  0.236494}, {-0.0354864, -0.0806469, -0.427695}, {0.0523367, \
-0.0864245, 0.0123651}, {0.119699, 0.106009, -0.19543}, {-0.237875, 
  0.100875, -0.0379863}, {-0.0133786, 0.208801, 
  0.139159}, {-0.0789777, -0.0445715, 
  0.471835}, {0.0580981, -0.479308, 0.1078}, {0.00951103, 
  0.353189, -0.274635}, {0.136587, 0.122729, -0.121958}, {0.0917791, 
  0.176609, -0.00765894}, {0.0766215, 0.270567, 0.107316}, {0.267982, 
  0.0636107, 0.189468}, {0.236227, 0.0276881, 
  0.183923}, {0.0255432, -0.0751076, -0.0388339}, {-0.0794804, 
  0.0838997, 
  0.0996038}, {-0.314095, -0.0708816, -0.178446}, {-0.284221, 
  0.334069, -0.0872689}, {0.363744, 0.0166169, 
  0.093344}, {0.121551, -0.100105, 0.380107}, {0.23604, 0.0569057, 
  0.38792}, {-0.319388, -0.0433301, 
  0.249595}, {-0.131647, -0.264032, -0.392399}, {-0.11539, 
  0.226879, -0.144566}, {-0.372802, 
  0.148128, -0.0679084}, {-0.0527082, -0.139595, 
  0.406245}, {0.379939, -0.117872, 
  0.267588}, {-0.00754746, -0.270367, -0.16394}, {0.285088, 
  0.366212, -0.120402}, {-0.228612, 
  0.198966, -0.0413564}, {-0.0695243, 0.228831, 
  0.310606}, {-0.0185919, -0.127638, 
  0.255294}, {-0.0643242, -0.0438049, 0.306055}, {-0.02503, 0.136594, 
  0.222897}, {0.361252, -0.083875, -0.210309}, {0.124148, -0.088297, 
  0.438816}, {0.0934764, -0.0060672, 0.406322}, {-0.157122, 
  0.123662, -0.107014}, {-0.225229, 
  0.34004, -0.0173769}, {-0.245439, -0.21116, -0.232369}, {-0.263058, 
  0.0711449, -0.0475782}, {0.0561782, 0.371226, 
  0.0823994}, {-0.313402, 0.348728, 0.0647438}, {-0.372396, 0.0456944,
   0.2018}, {-0.305162, 0.185094, -0.150585}, {0.427964, -0.047039, 
  0.147645}, {0.0351547, -0.0801259, 0.240481}, {-0.22392, 
  0.245518, -0.146075}, {-0.249104, 
  0.0135086, -0.214365}, {-0.0295494, 0.358549, 
  0.0248196}, {0.0214249, 0.0418008, -0.121127}, {-0.124509, 
  0.0740812, 0.24271}, {0.0358451, 0.304136, -0.321941}, {-0.0428418, 
  0.0436687, 0.0691292}, {0.146701, -0.358512, 
  0.178059}, {-0.347569, -0.133691, -0.0877818}, {0.237298, 
  0.138646, -0.313942}, {-0.102614, -0.0445136, -0.323943}, {0.247947,
   0.0629153, 0.355143}, {-0.0913594, 0.373381, -0.283786}, {0.354172,
   0.238702, -0.202986}, {-0.275126, 0.123973, 0.150425}, {0.242781, 
  0.0132999, -0.188597}, {-0.300019, -0.32802, 
  0.149591}, {-0.257192, -0.161819, -0.359985}, {0.106258, 
  0.376567, -0.27741}, {0.399343, 0.134582, -0.0825968}, {0.171001, 
  0.0576799, 0.210837}, {0.169544, 0.0878708, 0.237529}, {0.160805, 
  0.308583, -0.0307856}, {-0.286651, 0.146972, 0.317123}, {-0.0413955,
   0.368048, -0.277891}, {-0.045329, 
  0.373993, -0.238419}, {0.253813, -0.176811, -0.258647}, {0.188291, 
  0.043927, 0.169942}, {-0.380336, 
  0.21757, -0.0883575}, {-0.181126, -0.269599, 
  0.205608}, {0.0580155, -0.24121, -0.221364}, {0.278236, -0.0408339, 
  0.303578}, {-0.263226, 0.071545, 0.25498}, {-0.185009, -0.0871169, 
  0.200892}, {-0.293421, 0.175061, -0.130897}, {-0.0240582, -0.300139,
   0.0312728}, {0.199186, 0.315046, 0.30621}, {0.316807, 
  0.228106, -0.2433}, {-0.234723, 
  0.0681115, -0.425946}, {-0.0125268, -0.154082, -0.425306}, {0.16072,
   0.0224764, -0.191639}, {0.112422, -0.118494, 
  0.000410277}, {0.363384, -0.0123722, -0.210847}, {-0.258489, 
  0.0692653, 0.162093}, {0.299554, -0.0636423, 
  0.0673838}, {-0.0171694, -0.369789, -0.0309178}, {0.249, -0.253969, 
  0.183246}, {0.283385, 0.037596, -0.354623}, {-0.105666, -0.282629, 
  0.327178}, {-0.366281, 0.117831, 
  0.236087}, {0.057034, -0.0280531, -0.0975932}, {-0.126148, \
-0.343113, -0.126504}, {0.205869, 0.0811727, 0.0380468}, {-0.319399, 
  0.299681, 0.123871}, {-0.074883, -0.0748081, 0.402831}, {-0.211894, 
  0.266951, 0.248711}, {-0.0417049, -0.237115, -0.286403}, {0.119266, 
  0.252092, 0.268122}, {0.260285, 0.00295147, 0.350007}, {0.201717, 
  0.057768, 0.160622}, {0.114651, 0.385952, 0.0772721}, {-0.264957, 
  0.205695, -0.230753}, {-0.0044166, 
  0.345193, -0.0859375}, {0.248116, -0.244682, 0.121356}, {0.114786, 
  0.361339, 0.320958}, {0.120654, 0.0978149, 0.370193}, {-0.197614, 
  0.212589, -0.277458}, {0.122442, -0.333175, 
  0.0455025}, {0.0783302, -0.186115, -0.0804465}, {0.00136689, 
  0.219445, 0.238979}, {0.160957, 0.378214, 
  0.112008}, {-0.127105, -0.375088, -0.00384864}, {0.379402, \
-0.175559, 0.225076}, {-0.377584, 0.259401, 
  0.0276657}, {-0.250695, -0.256304, 0.329342}, {0.27458, 
  0.183443, -0.316944}, {0.00105066, 
  0.256426, -0.426039}, {-0.0364576, 
  0.173932, -0.454437}, {0.0643381, -0.133635, -0.4442}, {0.101149, \
-0.0129246, -0.378917}, {-0.262528, -0.265905, -0.253993}, {0.323865, 
  0.0590697, 0.109029}, {-0.145109, 0.352217, 
  0.164268}, {0.0687204, -0.292824, -0.367278}, {-0.192922, 0.235628, 
  0.222414}, {0.324101, -0.232779, 0.260586}, {-0.357507, -0.271307, 
  0.079428}, {-0.379562, 0.232325, -0.146899}, {-0.0453677, 0.12906, 
  0.253871}, {-0.333485, -0.13404, -0.0889925}, {0.159303, \
-0.0827022, -0.0467089}, {-0.0176576, 0.0524363, 
  0.214319}, {-0.39892, -0.220814, -0.0403824}, {-0.193744, 0.0499421,
   0.0935809}, {-0.168783, -0.174647, 
  0.391644}, {0.0775125, -0.0956388, 0.311655}, {-0.162502, 
  0.0863294, -0.149953}, {0.118231, -0.289254, -0.1885}, {0.31458, \
-0.0822987, 0.333298}, {-0.0265066, -0.159339, 
  0.0775164}, {0.075023, -0.458922, -0.04915}, {-0.31433, 0.0790437, 
  0.0226524}, {-0.18396, -0.366237, 
  0.139728}, {-0.0201362, -0.0885075, -0.461744}, {-0.0274688, \
-0.141348, 0.301591}, {-0.152369, 0.161729, 0.394911}, {-0.14111, 
  0.394918, 0.0526452}, {-0.0319812, -0.46199, -0.110949}, {0.264096, 
  0.135791, -0.233258}, {0.121294, 0.428942, -0.197589}, {-0.376575, 
  0.077007, -0.149423}, {0.302118, 0.155899, 0.102042}, {-0.157945, 
  0.156591, 0.166733}, {0.0816087, -0.380903, -0.216196}, {0.104778, 
  0.26092, -0.3557}, {0.0518215, -0.150876, 0.331946}, {-0.0634556, 
  0.197894, 0.450869}, {0.0209913, -0.33618, 0.279061}, {0.0443835, 
  0.0540037, -0.0543595}, {0.0612056, -0.227084, -0.408199}, \
{0.294732, -0.315891, -0.090153}, {0.277494, 0.14661, 
  0.377768}, {-0.152019, -0.271332, -0.0223613}, {-0.33407, -0.13453, 
  0.106211}, {-0.215915, -0.236466, -0.228223}, {-0.14588, 0.0443237, 
  0.153445}, {0.0738293, 0.0149296, -0.177607}, {-0.0576445, 
  0.0423788, 0.17337}, {-0.355487, 
  0.114773, -0.229528}, {-0.0180662, -0.339972, 0.11919}, {0.111151, 
  0.165253, -0.0634457}, {0.240749, 0.133644, 0.232236}, {0.0271161, 
  0.0422634, -0.0946122}, {-0.315931, 
  0.0630922, -0.0775106}, {-0.193407, 0.258941, 
  0.0737606}, {0.0307292, 0.217856, 0.0893802}, {-0.313181, 
  0.136813, -0.347238}, {0.253205, 
  0.133095, -0.316526}, {-0.0897819, -0.0281807, -0.299978}, \
{-0.324464, 0.0808906, 0.298461}, {0.0181875, 
  0.0402628, -0.153121}, {0.0193733, -0.00398711, 
  0.028432}, {-0.0741252, -0.14038, 0.215875}, {-0.29126, 0.00166267, 
  0.327661}, {-0.170906, 0.144917, 
  0.325219}, {0.114894, -0.0178741, -0.484509}, {-0.110815, -0.345338,
   0.0380702}, {0.274276, 
  0.111665, -0.22486}, {0.356395, -0.0763606, -0.073473}, {0.174221, 
  0.322201, 0.322982}, {0.135695, -0.103999, 
  0.0638573}, {-0.244125, -0.251069, -0.272266}, {0.150361, -0.071685,
   0.175707}, {-0.355213, 0.321585, 0.0602232}, {0.0531958, 0.439859, 
  0.131771}, {0.0735193, -0.167385, 0.218912}, {-0.105867, 
  0.22884, -0.307002}, {0.283726, 0.123848, 0.0825385}, {0.0481213, 
  0.386823, 
  0.292371}, {0.211349, -0.149821, -0.0652846}, {-0.171374, -0.218551,
   0.235945}, {-0.258513, 0.0697724, 0.28104}, {0.197763, 0.199343, 
  0.150405}, {-0.424986, -0.173731, -0.150083}, {-0.339909, 0.099307, 
  0.275845}, {-0.231581, -0.351731, 
  0.220064}, {-0.0472898, -0.0662388, 0.0655222}, {0.305405, 
  0.0488596, 0.198681}, {0.135647, 
  0.160868, -0.306148}, {0.0615609, -0.21674, -0.272785}, {-0.094513, \
-0.286596, -0.243422}, {-0.134929, 
  0.261358, -0.120669}, {-0.106643, -0.258416, 0.280877}, {0.18763, 
  0.0766481, -0.19389}, {-0.00657972, -0.224443, 0.360083}, {-0.19276,
   0.024885, -0.117635}, {-0.0504262, 
  0.372413, -0.308827}, {0.150857, -0.0746642, -0.0869272}, {0.31657, 
  0.243171, -0.275614}, {-0.278852, -0.181888, 0.361149}, {-0.245527, 
  0.0367309, -0.0145651}, {0.13973, -0.36818, -0.279282}, {-0.176562, 
  0.00359617, -0.0210767}, {0.26237, 
  0.0718238, -0.222621}, {-0.476828, 0.0830933, 
  0.0807725}, {0.0911013, -0.0440542, 0.111189}, {-0.317912, 0.179125,
   0.0550082}, {-0.0546225, 0.461865, -0.0305195}, {0.0200179, 
  0.323709, -0.3588}, {0.201723, -0.195993, 
  0.120212}, {0.254305, -0.308745, -0.134771}, {-0.36521, -0.0413517, 
  0.135229}, {-0.226906, 0.158093, 
  0.0766093}, {0.104997, -0.287581, -0.14574}, {-0.120054, 0.0129561, 
  0.177475}, {-0.049565, -0.260548, 0.274279}, {0.0216746, 
  0.13606, -0.217531}, {0.118083, -0.159232, -0.0903667}, {0.232687, 
  0.354888, 0.109648}, {0.0776943, -0.438638, 
  0.114135}, {-0.325342, -0.143804, -0.105551}, {0.173572, 0.191171, 
  0.116473}, {-0.0701164, -0.281797, 0.264197}, {-0.427541, 
  0.229488, -0.116843}, {-0.0330585, -0.190456, -0.225232}, \
{0.428262, -0.0173075, 
  0.0456925}, {-0.170616, -0.0684391, -0.0392803}, {0.329875, 
  0.309881, -0.0448547}, {0.11615, -0.2677, -0.203151}, \
{0.0000735578, -0.166473, -0.0274383}, {-0.0831802, -0.246, 
  0.350266}, {0.226694, -0.102301, 
  0.0646817}, {0.336988, -0.127553, -0.102884}, {-0.322168, 0.256537, 
  0.0536384}, {-0.192655, 
  0.177477, -0.320945}, {0.044057, -0.450063, -0.0029734}, {-0.107643,
   0.385553, -0.196376}, {-0.399681, 0.0752792, 
  0.216244}, {0.118163, -0.321732, -0.153124}, {-0.100936, -0.423116, 
  0.244851}, {0.12038, -0.439229, 0.127195}, {0.128949, -0.435498, 
  0.123277}, {-0.248193, -0.0807041, 0.328234}, {-0.296248, -0.115705,
   0.157598}, {0.340163, 0.00368185, 0.169269}, {-0.0471743, 0.200573,
   0.29628}, {0.4338, 0.0553706, 0.168181}, {-0.181472, 0.0445208, 
  0.250322}, {0.273209, 0.113932, -0.351646}, {0.258967, -0.385492, 
  0.0423207}, {-0.0805239, 0.469333, 0.102636}, {0.106876, 
  0.292678, -0.0396791}, {0.175028, -0.201957, 
  0.01378}, {-0.0691023, -0.416955, 0.108138}, {-0.0487711, 
  0.285926, -0.0057458}, {-0.217653, -0.354902, 0.0749812}, {0.145872,
   0.137018, -0.210744}, {0.140737, 
  0.390888, -0.273738}, {-0.332148, -0.222429, 
  0.103937}, {-0.0127704, -0.197893, 
  0.357933}, {-0.0358657, -0.275052, -0.101985}, {-0.0709502, \
-0.0468802, -0.0349508}, {0.00920052, 0.0239436, 
  0.46077}, {-0.118116, -0.26227, -0.363025}, {-0.202026, -0.0465944, \
-0.424665}, {-0.0633891, -0.258898, 
  0.173341}, {0.28849, -0.0279048, -0.183442}, {-0.0882698, \
-0.246445, -0.169729}, {-0.175464, 0.237234, 0.172367}, {0.258921, 
  0.045582, 0.307085}, {-0.0128848, -0.0707558, 0.141331}, {0.0411713,
   0.0392501, 0.480349}, {-0.459926, -0.0622083, 
  0.0371459}, {-0.168387, 0.102709, 
  0.285258}, {0.0283421, -0.00131161, -0.274813}, {-0.121811, 
  0.121832, 0.176423}, {-0.207796, -0.235886, 0.13267}, {0.257091, 
  0.0896842, 
  0.340699}, {-0.0435173, -0.0872813, -0.222219}, {0.32965, \
-0.0257101, -0.333532}, {-0.0123904, -0.205362, -0.0492945}, \
{-0.00374312, -0.122497, -0.0205081}, {-0.135492, -0.423707, 
  0.0112884}, {0.0855583, -0.20552, -0.271127}, {0.198649, 
  0.0406285, -0.296877}, {-0.230212, 0.409579, 0.0399353}, {-0.452558,
   0.0559992, 0.19909}, {0.0670604, 0.410149, 0.118522}, {0.113365, 
  0.388761, -0.185765}, {-0.284982, -0.185966, 0.0956176}, {-0.367122,
   0.151086, 0.013446}, {-0.13606, -0.0289856, -0.267088}, {0.32855, 
  0.347015, -0.0623143}, {0.281237, -0.237738, 0.0344766}, {-0.283702,
   0.114793, -0.362203}, {0.0544594, 0.40848, 
  0.0331266}, {-0.00306673, 
  0.180276, -0.306617}, {-0.183769, -0.248097, -0.273307}, \
{-0.319877, -0.118518, 0.189593}, {0.386179, 
  0.171294, -0.196063}, {0.0281778, 0.333756, 0.0297884}, {-0.271359, 
  0.27836, -0.14529}, {0.175791, 0.0460925, 0.317398}, {0.368903, 
  0.290425, 
  0.104289}, {0.0854183, -0.190501, -0.0749644}, {0.233837, \
-0.150364, -0.132877}, {-0.194878, -0.0461417, 0.170231}, {0.0650695, 
  0.239872, -0.0532696}, {0.195173, 0.166812, 0.40727}, {-0.127956, 
  0.0190897, -0.291256}, {0.000327004, 0.125645, 
  0.412696}, {-0.0634454, 0.021494, 0.165368}, {0.203221, 0.41112, 
  0.0953959}, {-0.437772, -0.0882882, -0.145906}, {-0.125122, \
-0.158808, 0.365549}, {0.377208, 
  0.0957857, -0.0650256}, {0.163844, -0.289452, 0.04087}, {-0.118032, 
  0.347671, -0.0589331}, {-0.104193, -0.354164, 0.0371428}, {0.11035, 
  0.163427, -0.0781963}, {0.225555, 0.0646801, 0.0906122}, {0.254457, 
  0.255568, 0.108571}, {0.0348967, 
  0.113241, -0.143774}, {-0.212108, -0.1689, 
  0.393093}, {0.0388735, -0.0965032, 0.0131755}, {-0.376204, 
  0.0168187, -0.17311}, {-0.247236, -0.0181788, -0.0901608}, \
{-0.235913, -0.200818, -0.28977}, {-0.225951, -0.370151, 
  0.15547}, {0.164595, 0.312376, 0.191215}, {0.252232, 
  0.352291, -0.0666086}, {0.0636305, 
  0.0551431, -0.320086}, {-0.101837, 0.136179, -0.307489}, {0.26988, 
  0.205582, 0.302639}, {0.448347, 0.0338968, 0.211475}, {0.244571, 
  0.430572, 0.00866577}, {-0.483539, 
  0.0703613, -0.0222452}, {-0.342417, 0.240303, 
  0.0249563}, {-0.105054, -0.208471, -0.391206}, {-0.3052, 
  0.122527, -0.0715492}, {-0.237835, -0.225626, 0.367042}, {0.204351, 
  0.117914, -0.205332}, {0.200975, 0.0593003, 0.419638}, {-0.285721, 
  0.125161, 0.00917914}, {0.0970362, -0.267208, 
  0.315556}, {0.00367884, 0.1155, 
  0.00571519}, {0.145617, -0.0866807, -0.172231}, {0.347231, 0.241364,
   0.108395}, {0.367131, 
  0.0706766, -0.106752}, {-0.321655, -0.0354279, 0.370318}, {0.175434,
   0.0978661, -0.111606}, {0.156561, -0.181061, -0.240112}, \
{-0.225779, 0.332968, 0.222788}, {0.0327132, 
  0.0106739, -0.210262}, {0.357146, -0.283004, -0.0222472}, \
{-0.0148514, 0.067042, 0.478155}, {-0.135356, 
  0.0388469, -0.26114}, {-0.0378716, -0.160818, -0.0952727}, \
{-0.208757, 0.127752, 
  0.0774037}, {0.061194, -0.226776, -0.0936658}, {-0.167118, 0.219427,
   0.23075}, {0.214108, -0.090262, 
  0.0225281}, {-0.0342962, -0.276786, -0.0321186}, {-0.118255, 
  0.0774748, 0.0503613}, {0.223318, 0.32263, 0.291692}, {0.428135, 
  0.139352, 0.0366396}, {-0.238528, -0.240793, 0.201097}, {0.0979179, 
  0.292543, 0.172217}, {-0.00822002, 0.341306, -0.169648}, {0.238745, 
  0.0543195, 0.104786}, {0.0059195, 
  0.315684, -0.244171}, {0.123782, -0.302633, -0.280843}, {-0.0934687,
   0.0422916, 0.458815}, {-0.212951, -0.39138, -0.100392}, {-0.111945,
   0.200486, -0.235833}, {0.170065, 0.0820785, 0.0505151}, {-0.127091,
   0.31153, 0.0123755}, {-0.124636, 0.266947, 0.321725}, {0.139601, 
  0.340457, 0.0178311}, {0.186608, -0.421323, 0.151959}, {-0.148742, 
  0.180169, -0.141162}, {-0.230315, 
  0.135904, -0.344872}, {0.168384, -0.383118, -0.23245}, {0.0705697, 
  0.41286, -0.253787}, {-0.0707014, -0.0936947, -0.388207}, \
{0.0644795, -0.334768, -0.00555202}, {-0.131066, -0.348207, \
-0.20943}, {0.243346, -0.145128, -0.401305}, {-0.450589, -0.14033, \
-0.00891752}, {0.14812, -0.396323, 0.0124971}, {0.232824, 
  0.138863, -0.298182}, {0.124387, -0.424434, -0.0738467}, {0.0441845,
   0.0937891, -0.12616}, {0.24295, -0.376377, 0.0390774}, {-0.188488, 
  0.345704, -0.215744}, {-0.137181, 0.16966, 
  0.198257}, {0.165277, -0.349429, -0.0429299}, {0.0621409, -0.29064, 
  0.342801}, {0.358384, -0.0916271, 0.0788578}, {-0.345608, 
  0.0162664, -0.0132505}, {-0.0329251, 0.074156, 
  0.268012}, {-0.118621, 0.405769, 0.212522}, {0.127681, 0.333399, 
  0.275498}, {0.271657, 0.0820339, 
  0.254442}, {0.239329, -0.0299788, -0.436015}, {-0.00699772, \
-0.0745621, -0.089588}, {0.0516803, -0.482106, -0.0844396}, \
{-0.0219902, 
  0.189688, -0.0214278}, {0.314256, -0.123922, -0.0342189}, \
{-0.374505, -0.0498333, -0.0431203}, {0.172392, -0.340127, 
  0.187827}, {-0.0727767, -0.139846, 0.144823}, {0.283381, -0.155654, 
  0.220004}, {0.383349, 0.132127, -0.160677}, {0.285632, 
  0.0011938, -0.407638}, {-0.0388909, 0.242295, 0.121682}, {-0.196232,
   0.35245, 0.09135}, {-0.261507, 
  0.0260906, -0.128202}, {0.0363302, -0.112134, -0.065769}, {0.329448,
   0.270598, 0.0756326}, {0.0189002, 0.244652, 
  0.184427}, {-0.114018, -0.0194057, 
  0.214152}, {-0.0729797, -0.00234346, 0.0959277}, {0.0833453, 
  0.0406415, 
  0.279057}, {0.413112, -0.00685161, -0.177889}, {0.0342486, \
-0.0695844, -0.447676}, {0.0153618, 0.0325779, 
  0.0379422}, {0.0888052, -0.184714, -0.35356}, {-0.0119569, \
-0.0479826, 0.0187195}, {0.424029, -0.153929, -0.116283}, {0.370228, 
  0.0898165, -0.204007}, {-0.0999399, 0.108642, -0.169057}, {0.227432,
   0.136856, 0.195269}, {0.111356, -0.031639, 0.0947817}, {-0.291649, 
  0.0509358, -0.331662}, {-0.305673, -0.0913778, -0.168418}, \
{0.184588, 0.161289, 0.101601}, {0.134371, 
  0.272089, -0.214515}, {0.06232, 0.0820928, 0.281062}, {0.258574, 
  0.33171, -0.0427287}, {0.031821, -0.441286, 0.110935}, {0.0777209, 
  0.252012, 0.224541}, {-0.0838177, 0.348947, 
  0.217236}, {0.232479, -0.00519838, -0.166565}, {-0.0777467, 
  0.081504, 
  0.363373}, {0.149706, -0.152843, -0.0412928}, {-0.013825, \
-0.328487, -0.282468}, {0.239132, -0.0417143, 0.331609}, {-0.356339, 
  0.13982, -0.254708}, {-0.12837, -0.153319, 
  0.284842}, {-0.180303, -0.4078, 
  0.188908}, {-0.0542773, -0.178778, -0.00670058}, {-0.397813, \
-0.0853628, -0.256818}, {0.106191, 0.366329, 0.212002}, {-0.371361, 
  0.139013, -0.237454}, {-0.262497, -0.299795, 
  0.292114}, {-0.296075, -0.0285252, 0.301595}, {0.126426, 
  0.178736, -0.0302353}, {-0.213735, -0.314002, -0.158637}}
```

I would like to plot them in 3d density form. I mean I want these points to be transparent ans give me smooth pattern like this :

[image]

Comment: Something like: `BinCounts[datt, #, #, #] &@.02 // 
  GaussianFilter[#, 7] & // {ListDensityPlot3D[#, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], 
   ListSliceDensityPlot3D[#, {"ZStackedPlanes", 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]} &`?

Comment: @Kuba Neat! only point is the scaling of the axes.

Comment: Have you seen `SmoothDensityHistogram[]`?

Comment: Maybe: `nf = Nearest[pts -> "Distance"]; func[pt_] := First[nf[pt]]
DensityPlot3D[func[{x, y, z}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]` ??

Answer (score 4):

Converting the comment to an answer to get it from unanswered stack:

```
BinCounts[datt, #, #, #] & @ .02 // 
  GaussianFilter[#, 7] & // 
  { ListDensityPlot3D[#, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
  , ListSliceDensityPlot3D[#, {"ZStackedPlanes", 1}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
  } &
```

[image]